# Component array state added element gets deleted

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of servers and an AddServer button. I keep an array of servers as state, but when I add a server it immediately gets deleted. Anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Here is a video which demonstrates the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajS4_WQ4mn8

Here is part of the code I'm using:

```
import { SERVERS } from '../shared/servers';

class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            servers: SERVERS,
            selectedServer: null
        }

        this.handleToggle = this.ToggleServer.bind(this);
        this.HandleAddServer = this.HandleAddServer.bind(this);
    }

    HandleAddServer = (servername , serverip, servertype) => {
    const serverslist = [...this.state.servers];
    const newid = serverslist[serverslist.length -1].id +1;
    
    serverslist.push({
        
            ip: serverip,
            id: newid,
            servername: servername,
            Type: servertype,
            IsRunning: false

    });
     
    this.setState({ servers: serverslist });
}
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: What is `SERVERS` and why are you mutating it?

Comment: I start with importing a file which is nothing but an array of servers object, its actually the first servers I've got by default. Should I add the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, and no wonder it was hard to catch.... I used a reactstrap button inside a form tag, and if you use a button in form using the usual on submit it causes a page to refresh. It's written here: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1510

The solution to fix it is to use the onClick attribute inside the form button and delete the onsubmit.

Comment: The issue is more likely that the button has `type="submit"` and is was submitting the form. In the `onSubmit` handler you should call `event.preventDefault()` on the submit event to keep the page/app from reloading.

Comment: Damm you are a pro! :D. Although I'm not passing the event to the handler as argument, since the form is in a different component then I pass the addserver function as props argument. So it's kind of tricky :). I just used the onClick argument for the button and it worked.

Comment: Anyhow really thanks for your help! I never thought that my button is the one causing the page to refresh !

Comment: Well, if the button *isn't* your actual submit button you should specify `type="button"` since buttons are submit buttons by default if you don't specify the `type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a mutation issue, but instead of mutating your state you are mutating *some* external array which your state is holding a reference to, which indirectly mutates the state.

Don't mutate state!

Create a new array reference for the `servers` state.

```
HandleAddServer = (servername , serverip, servertype) => {
  const newid = this.state.servers[this.state.servers.length -1].id + 1;
    
  this.setState({
    servers: [
      ...this.state.servers,
      {
        ip: serverip,
        id: newid,
        servername: servername,
        Type: servertype,
        IsRunning: false
      },
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: I believe I have tried to only work with a copy of the servers in the AddServer function and it didn't work as well. But I'll give your solution a try.

Comment: Have a look on the new HandleAddServer, it doesn't mutating the state and yet the problem persist. Could it be that in the constructor my SERVER import is being a new state again? And if so, how to solve it?

Comment: I have also tried to use setState as you did but it didn't work as well.

Comment: @mashtock Your updated `handleAddServer` looks like it should work. Can you clarify what isn't working? Can you try creating a minimal *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: hmmm I'll try to make a codesandbox but it might take a while, but I have posted a video to show what is wrong. The new added server line gets completely deleted after 0.5 seconds or so.

Comment: @mashtock Yeah, sorry, I don't generally click links into random google drive URLs. Try posting it to youtube and link from there?

Comment: If the state is "resetting" after a short duration I am thinking you have some asynchronous code at play and this `Main` component is being remounted.

Comment: I have changed the link to youtube, you are probably right but I don't really have too much experience in react so I'm not sure what is wrong really

Comment: I managed to find the solution, thanks alot for your help. Only thanks to my struggle to make a codesandbox for this I was able to catch it.